# GDI calls do not work in WPF application when called the 1st time

Tags: c#, wpf, gdi+

The following test function

1. works when called form a console application
2. does *not* work when called the 1st time in a WPF application.
   A .png file of size 200 x 200 is created with "empty" pixels (ARGB=0x00000000).
3. works when called a 2nd time (just one the next line) in WPF application
4. works when called from a different thread

(Pls do not discuss why using GDI here.)

```
using System.Drawing;
...
class SomeClass
{
    ...
    public void Test(string name)
    {
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(200, 200))
        {
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                bmp.Save(Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp\" + name + ".png"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cases 2. and 3. are called from a (WPF) MenuItem.Command being executed.
Case 4 is also called during MenuItem.Command being executed but delegates to the thread pool (ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...)) for testing purpose.

The problem seems not to be the Save(..) method. Looks like the drawing method(s) (e.g. FillRectangle) of the Graphics do not work as expected (the Brushes look fine).

Comment: What is the debugger saying?

Comment: @sLw What do you exactly mean by "What is the debugger saying"? I checked Brushes .Green with the debugger and it looks ok. There are no exceptions either. When I add code to analyze the bitmap bits and they are zero.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works fine when called once in `App` constructor. Hard to imagine why it should not work.

Comment: @Clemens "... Cases 2. and 3. are called from a (WPF) MenuItem.Command being executed ...".

Comment: Maybe, but that shouldn't matter. It works on the first call for me. If you think there is something specific with a MenuItem Command, post enough details to make your issue reproducible.

Comment: It does matter. When calling at a different location it works, too. A workaround that seems to work is delegating the call to the dispatcher as Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => { Test(... synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot anwer my question but I can describe my workaround:
Instead of directly calling Test(...) delegating it to the dispatcher seems to help.

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => { Test("SomeName"); });
```